# Wrong expansion for the "$<" variable in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

***A makefile is:***

```make
all : foo ;


# A 'DEFAULT' special-target, providing a recipe to execute for target 'foo'.
.DEFAULT :
    @echo '$$@ is: "$@"'
    @echo '$$< is: "$<"'
```

***Executing, I get:***

```console
$@ is: "foo"
$< is: "foo"
```

How come here, that `$<` and `$@` expand to the same target?

Remember, that we had here:

1. A file `foo`, that Make is executing the recipe for. (Therefore, the expansion for `$@` is OK)
2. The target `foo` has no prerequisites, at all. (Hence, `$<` should expand to an **empty** string).

***To make it more absurd, let's try the following makefile:***

```make
.DEFAULT :
    @echo '$$< is "$<"'
    @echo '$$@ is "$@"'
```

***Running, we get:***

```console
$ make .DEFAULT
$< is ".DEFAULT"
$@ is ".DEFAULT"
```

Really, can we justify that `$<` and `$@` expand to the same string (`.DEFAULT`), when the target had no prerequisites at all, to begin with?

Answer (score 1):

Because `foo` is an implicit prerequisite of `.DEFAULT`, and [`$<` will include implicit prerequisites](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#index-_0024_003c).

> The name of the first prerequisite. If the target got its recipe from an implicit rule, this will be the first prerequisite added by the implicit rule (see Implicit Rules).